# Run function loaded from ecmascript 6 module

Tags: javascript, module, amd, ecmascript-6, traceur

I try to use ecmascript 6 modules system for first time. I use traceur compiler. Given two es6 files:

```
// app.js 
export function row() {
    alert('row');
}

// init.js
import { row } from 'public_js/app';
row();
```

Traceur (I use grunt-traceur task) compiles them to:

```
// app.js
System.register("public_js/app", [], function() {
  "use strict";
  var __moduleName = "public_js/app";
  function row() {
    alert('row');
  }
  return {get row() {
      return row;
    }};
});

// init.js
System.register("public_js/init", [], function() {
  "use strict";
  var __moduleName = "public_js/init";
  var row = System.get("public_js/app").row;
  row();
  return {};
});
```

I include compiled version of `init.js` to my HTML via simple script tag:

```
<script src="/path/to/compiled/init.js" type="module"></script>
```

And nothing happens. I don't see my alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're only declaring them, not requiring them.

Comment: Try adding type="module" to your script tag?

Comment: @BrianGenisio It was a typo, in my code I has type module, without it script throws errors that System is not defined.

Comment: @Bergi How can I require them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By pre-compiling your code as modules to ES5, you are now taking it out of the world of the automatic import/module loading system in ES6 and you need to use ES5 mechanisms to load it.  So, you need to include the compiled code **without the `type=module` attribute** and then `get()` the module that kicks off the rest of the world.

So, the following works for me:

```
<script src="/path/to/compiled/app.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/compiled/init.js"></script>
<script>
  System.get('public_js/init');
</script>
```

Since you are pre-compiling the code, I recommend that you concatenate all of the compiled code into a single JS file to avoid including them all.

If you use Traceur without compiling your code first, then you can live within the ES6 constructs.  This includes `type="module"` and/or `import 'module-name'`.

**Edit**
Thinking about this further, `app.js` is correctly compiled as a module.  `init.js`, however, doesn't need to be compiled as a module.  You are compiling the code with the `--module` flag.  If, instead, you compile `init.js` with the `--script` flag, it will not encapsulate the `init` code as a module, and you don't need to call `System.get` by hand.  Just something to think about.